# Qt: возможен ли неявный connect?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Мне дали доработать приложение написанное с использованием Qt. В приложении есть некий диалог унаследованный от QDialog. В этом диалоге есть QPushButton по имени btnCheck. Так же есть обработчик нажатия на эту кнопку:

```
private slots:
void on_btnCheck_clicked();
```

И нигде в этом проекте не вызывается connect связывающий сигнал clicked кнопки btnCheck со слотом on_btnCheck_clicked в этом диалоге. Поиск по файлам всего проекта находит всего лишь два вхождения слова on_btnCheck_clicked: при объявлении и при определении этой функции.

При этом фактически связь есть - при нажатии на кнопку вызывается этот обработчик.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как кроме вызова connect можно связать сигнал и слот? Просмотрел [документацию](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html), но там ничего про это не нашёл.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В "Signals & Slots", есть ссылка [automatic connections](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#automatic-connections) там написано, что, для этого надо чтобы имя слота было объявлено специальным образом:

```
void on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>);
```

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, в проекте используются UI файлы, которые обрабатываются uic, генерирующим код подключения автоматически. Подробнее можно почитать в [Widgets and Dialogs with Auto-Connect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect)